# Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR) Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database. (android)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

DATABASE HANDLER JAVA FILE

```
public class MyDbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME ="Dataa";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="Dataa";
    public static final String CLOUMN_ID="_id";
    public static final String CLOUMN_FIRST_NAME="_FirstName";
    public static final String CLOUMN_LAST_NAME="_LastName";
    public static final String CLOUMN_GENDER="_Gender";
    public static final String CLOUMN_CITY="_City";

    public MyDbHandler(Context context, String name , SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context , DATABASE_NAME, factory,DATABASE_VERSION );


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String query =  "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("+
                CLOUMN_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " +
                CLOUMN_FIRST_NAME +" TEXT " +
                CLOUMN_LAST_NAME +" TEXT " +
                CLOUMN_GENDER +" TEXT " +
                CLOUMN_CITY +" TEXT " +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + TABLE_NAME );
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Adding Record
    public void addData(Dataa dataaa )
    {
        ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
        values.put(CLOUMN_FIRST_NAME, dataaa.get_FirstName());
        values.put(CLOUMN_LAST_NAME, dataaa.get_LastName());
        values.put(CLOUMN_GENDER, dataaa.get_Gender());
        values.put(CLOUMN_CITY, dataaa.getCity());
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    //Print
    public String databaseToString()
    {
        String dbString="";
        SQLiteDatabase db= getWritableDatabase();
        String query= "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +" WHERE 1";

        //cURSOR
        Cursor c= db.rawQuery(query,null);
        //move to first row
        c.moveToFirst();

        while(!c.isAfterLast())
        {

            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_FirstName"))!= null)
            {
                dbString +=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_FirstName"));
                dbString +="\n";
            }
        }
        db.close();
        return dbString;
    }

}
```

ERROR SCREENSHOT

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "_FirstName": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Dataa(_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT _FirstName TEXT _LastName TEXT _Gender TEXT _City TEXT );

                                                                                   Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                                                                                   Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                                                                                    (near "_FirstName": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Dataa(_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT _FirstName TEXT _LastName TEXT _Gender TEXT _City TEXT );)
                                                                                   #################################################################
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1058)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:623)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1812)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1743)
                                                                                       at com.example.useraccountname.sqli1.MyDbHandler.onCreate(MyDbHandler.java:38)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                                                       at com.example.useraccountname.sqli1.MyDbHandler.addData(MyDbHandler.java:56)
                                                                                       at com.example.useraccountname.sqli1.Ma
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add the comma (,) after `TEXT` or your Datatype as follows

```
String query =  "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("+
                CLOUMN_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                CLOUMN_FIRST_NAME +" TEXT, " +
                CLOUMN_LAST_NAME +" TEXT, " +
                CLOUMN_GENDER +" TEXT, " +
                CLOUMN_CITY +" TEXT " +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Rectify Your Query this way**

```
String query =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                    + CLOUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," + CLOUMN_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT ,"
                    + CLOUMN_LAST_NAME + " TEXT ,"
                    + CLOUMN_GENDER + " TEXT ,"
                    + CLOUMN_CITY + " TEXT" + ")";
                  db.execSQL(query);
```

Then **Uninstall old app and Run Again** .